# Restrict asset image filetypes

Tags: assets

Is it possible to further restrict asset filetypes than just "image"?

For example only allow .jpg, .jpeg and .png ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. If the only files you want to upload are .jpg, .jpeg, and .png, then yes: set [allowedFileExtensions](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#allowedFileExtensions) in your `config/general.php`

```
'allowedFileExtensions' => 'jpg, jpeg, png',
```

If you want those to be the only image filetypes, but  to allow other files for non-image assets, then that is harder (and I don't know how to do it).

Comment: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#extraAllowedFileExtensions should do it for the latter.